# How to write an element just after another with javascript?

Tags: javascript, element

I need to append an element onclick just after another (a textarea).

How do I do that?

Comment: Please post an example, i.e. the HTML you have and the HTML you want to get. Where is the `click` handler bound to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: This question may not answer the question properly but it was selected as the right answer. So I am adding the correct answer here since most people don't scroll past it and the original author hasn't accessed Stackoverflow for many years now.

## Correct answer from [@RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6174616/560299)

```
var div = document.getElementById( 'div' );
var newText = document.createElement( 'textarea' ); // create new textarea
div.parentNode.insertBefore( newText, div.nextSibling );
```

### Old Irrelevant answer:

<strike>You can use the appendChild method to add a new element</strike>

HTML

```
<div id='div'>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');

var newText = document.createElement('textarea'); // create new textarea

div.appendChild(newText); // add it to the div
```

Resulting HTML

```
<div id='div'>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want to add a textarea after a specific one and not after the last one ?

Comment: No, this is not the answer.

Comment: note that `getElementById` may not work in IE

Comment: @student `getElementById` may not work in IE?  are you serious? Have you ever used IE?

Comment: This does no insert after but inside at the end.

Comment: wrong answer. not related to question

Answer (score 132):

The accepted answer will work in this specific case, but to insert an element after another more generally, the following does the job:

```
someElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, someElement.nextSibling);
```

Where *newElement* is the element to be inserted and *someElement* is the element it is to be inserted after.

W3C [insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) method of the [Node interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247)

Comment: note that `nextSibling` may not work in IE

Comment: @student–[*nextSibling*](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#attribute-nextSibling) was introduced in DOM level 1 (1998) and works back to IE 5 at least.

Answer (score 8):

`outerHTML` method does the trick too:

```
allAloneElement.outerHTML+='<p>I am the new element</p>'
```

Comment: Like the accepted answer, this also assumes that the new element should go at the end.