# Wrap Table with DIV at runtime

Tags: javascript, css, html, scrollbar

My first question here.

Given a table:

```
<table id="mytable">
 <tr><td>row1 col1</td><td>row1 col2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row2 col1</td><td>row2 col2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I know that if I were to wrap the above with `<div style="overflow-x:scroll;">` , I will have a horizontal scrollbar underneath the table. Unfortunately, I can't alter the way the table / html is written. I can only manipulate the contents via javascript.

I tried:

```
document.getElementByID("mytable").style.overflowX = scroll;
```

but it didn't work.

Any idea if it can be done? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please be more specific! what is your aim? you want to scroll your data? or something? you have not specified that.

Comment: Jax, did you get it done? if yes mark answer as right to set question as resolved, and if not, then comment what is progress please.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to have horizontal scrolling capability on the system generated table. 

I did try the code you gave below. Worked like a charm.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
$("#yorutable").wrap($("<div />").css("overflow-x":"scroll"));
```

to warp your table with a div run time.

If you can not add jquery, you can do something like

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('yourtable'); 
var parent = tbl.parentNode;
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.style.overflowX="scroll"; 
wrapper.appendChild(tbl);
parent.appendChild(wrapper);
```

Comment: he will need to include `jQuery` for this

Answer (score 5):

Pratik's solution was educational, but not 100% correct.  It will work if the table is the last item in its parent; otherwise it reorders the table to be last. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173941/how-to-write-an-element-just-after-another-with-javascript) tells the rest of the story.

Putting the whole story together:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('yourtable'); 
var parent = tbl.parentNode;
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.style.overflowX="scroll"; 
parent.insertBefore( wrapper, tbl );
wrapper.appendChild(tbl);
```