# How to change Tuleap Login screen

Tags: php, docker, tuleap

I am trying to customize (by adding a text message) the default [Tuleap](https://www.tuleap.org/) login screen (see picute below) of my company.

[image]

Although the Tuleap Project is well documented, I am unable to find the right HTML (or PHP) file. Can someone help me out there?

**EDIT:** Sorry I forgot to mention that I run Tuleap under Docker with Ubuntu.

Comment: Why you don't customize the css ?

Comment: @executable Thanks for you response. Cause I want to add a text message on the login screen and don't want to change the style. Maybe I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I think something like that would make it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173941/how-to-write-an-element-just-after-another-with-javascript

Comment: But in this way I would have to include the javascript file and there again I don't know where the File containing the HTML markup is stored. I guess that Tuleap use some kind of template to render the HTML-Page but I have no idea which one.

Comment: Well you can open the browser console and look at the network tab to see where the files are located.

Comment: I had the same Idea but unfortunately it didn't really help https://ibb.co/b8QUWo

Comment: I suggest to open your webproject on IDE and try to find an ID from your web login page and then you can add your custom JS on that page.